# No puedo resolver un ejemplo indexOf

Tags: javascript

Perdon pero hace unos dias comence a estudiar y estoy con unos ejercicios que me dan error.
Copio la consigna

Para lograrlo, tendremos que crear una función llamada menciona, que recibirá dos parámetros: un texto —que es donde vamos a buscar— y una palabra —que es la que vamos a averiguar si se menciona en el texto—. La misma función retorna true en el caso de encontrar la palabra.

Lo que yo pongo

```js
 function menciona (texto,palabra){
      
   return texto.indexOf(palabra)
    
}
console.log(menciona("Hola como estas"))
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el error?

Comment: Errores:
Al llamar a la función menciona("Hola mundo","Hola") debe retornar true
Al llamar a la función menciona("Se dice de mi","mi") debe retornar true
Al llamar a la función menciona("Estoy programando","mundo") debe retornar false

Comment: Errores: 1. estás pasando un único parámetro a la función, y 2. indexOf devuelve un número, no true o false

Answer (score 1):

El código no da error, está funcionando perfectamente. El problema es que no hace lo que tú esperas que haga.

La función `indexOf` retorna el índice donde se encuentra lo que se está buscando, si no lo encuentra retorna -1. Eso es lo que tu código hace.

Si quieres que retorne `true` o `false` tienes que condicionar el valor devuelto por `indexOf`

```js
function menciona (texto,palabra){
   let index = texto.indexOf(palabra)
   
   // si el valor es mayor que -1 es porque se encontró la palabra
   // y la expresión resuelve a true
   // de lo contrario resolverá a false
   return index > -1
    
}
console.log(menciona("Hola como estas", "Hola"))
```